# Como funcionam os encontros vocálicos?

Tags: ditongo, hiato

Encontro vocálico é a junção de duas ou mais vogais dentro das palavras, correto?

Gostaria de entender melhor os encontros vocálicos:

- Ditongos
- Tritongos
- Hiatos

Especificamente nos ditongos ouço sobre aberto e fechado ou oral e nasal. Como funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quando juntamos duas ou mais vogais em uma palavra, temos um encontro
>   vocálico.
>
> Os encontros vocálicos são divididos em três tipos: DITONGO, TRITONGO
>   e HIATO.
>
> HIATO: quando duas vogais estão juntas na mesma palavra, mas em
>   sílabas diferentes.
>
> Ex:
>
> SA-Ú-DE
>
> PA-RA-Í-BA
>
> SO-AR
>
> OBS: em caso de as vogais fazerem parte da mesma sílaba, trata-se de
>   um ditongo e não de um hiato.
>
> Vejamos os exemplos das palavras “sábia” e “sabiá”:
>
> Sá-bia (o encontro vocálico “ia” é um ditongo, porque as duas vogais
>   estão em sequência e fazem parte da mesma sílaba).
>
> Sa-bi-á (o encontro vocálico “iá" é um hiato, pois embora as duas
>   vogais estejam juntas, elas pertencem a sílabas diferentes).
>
> OBS:
>
> O hiato é formado por VOGAL + VOGAL.
>
> Isso acontece pelo fato de as vogais pertencerem a sílabas diferentes,
>   e portanto servirem como núcleos para suas respectivas sílabas.
>   Acontece diferente com o ditongo, que pode ser formado por vogal +
>   semivogal ou semivogal + vogal, e com o tritongo, que é formado por
>   semivogal + vogal + semivogal.
>
> Há ainda casos como o da palavra “sereia”:
>
> Se-rei-a
>
> - O encontro vocálico “eia” não é tritongo, pois as três vogais não pertencem a uma única sílaba.
> - O encontro vocálico “ei” constitui um ditongo decrescente, pois é formado por vogal + semivogal, já que ambas pertencem a uma única
>     sílaba.
> - O encontro vocálico “ia” constitui um hiato, pois apesar de estarem adjacentes, as duas vogais pertencem a sílabas diferentes.
> - A particularidade deste hiato é que ele é formado por SEMIVOGAL + VOGAL, já que o ditongo “ei” é decrescente, e o “i” é semivogal. Mesmo
>     assim, permanece a regra de que cada sílaba precisa possuir uma vogal,
>     e não pode ter mais de uma, sendo as demais classificadas como
>     semivogais.

fonte: [InfoEscola - Hiato](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/hiato/)

> Quando juntamos duas ou mais vogais em uma palavra, temos um encontro
>   vocálico.
>
> Os encontros vocálicos são divididos em três tipos: DITONGO, TRITONGO
>   e HIATO.
>
> DITONGO: quando dois sons vocálicos (vogais) estão juntas na mesma
>   sílaba.
>
> Ex:
>
> PEIXE SAUDADE PAIXÃO O ditongo pode ser classificado de duas formas:
>
> Ditongo crescente ou Ditongo decrescente Ditongo oral ou Ditongo nasal
>   Para entendermos como acontece a classificação de crescente ou
>   decrescente, temos que saber distinguir uma vogal de uma semivogal.
>
> Toda vez que uma vogal está sozinha na sílaba, ela classifica-se como
>   vogal, mas quando ela está junto a outra vogal ela pode ficar em menos
>   evidência, mais “fraca” ou “escondida”, estas são as chamadas
>   semivogais.
>
> Ex:
>
> APAIXONADO: neste caso a sílaba -PAI- contém duas vogais. A mais
>   aberta ou “forte” é a letra A, enquanto que a letra I é mais fechada e
>   “fraca”. Neste caso, diz-se que é a junção da vogal A + a semivogal I.
>
> Ditongo crescente É quando há na sílaba a junção de semivogal + vogal
>
> Ex: qua-dra-do (u=SV, a=V)
>
> Ditongo Decrescente É quando, na mesma sílaba, junta-se vogal +
>   semivogal
>
> Ex: noi-te (o=V, i=SV)
>
> Para compreendermos o que é um ditongo oral ou um ditongo nasal,
>   precisamos entender que há vogais que são pronunciadas somente pela
>   boca, chamadas de vogais orais (a, é, ê, i, ó, ô, u), e há vogais que
>   são pronunciadas também pelo nariz, chamadas de vogais nasais.
>
> Ditongo oral É quando há uma junção de duas vogais orais na mesma
>   sílaba.
>
> Ex: cai-xa
>
> Ditongo nasal É quando há uma junção de duas vogais nasais ou de uma
>   vogal nasal e uma oral na mesma sílaba.
>
> Ex: sa-bão
>
> Arquivado em: Linguística, Português

Fonte: http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/ditongo/

Answer (score 1):

- **Ai**, isso doeu.
- Estás **aí**?
- Quatro, água, qual.

No primeiro exemplo trata-se de um ditongo decrescente. Isto é, começas com a pronunciação de uma vogal e num mesmo esforço de voz pronuncias uma outra mais fraca (semivogal).

No segundo exemplo trata-se de um hiato, isto é, cada vogal é pronunciada de forma independente e não num unico esforço de voz.

No terceiro exemplo trata-se de palavras com ditongos crescentes, isto é, começa-se com uma semivogal e termina-se com uma vogal.